# Laravel looping through array in blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have the following array:

```
$days = [
    ['dow' => 1, 'day' => 'Monday'],
    ['dow' => 2, 'day' => 'Tuesday'],
    ['dow' => 3, 'day' => 'Wednesday'],
    ['dow' => 4, 'day' => 'Thursday'],
    ['dow' => 5, 'day' => 'Friday'],
    ['dow' => 6, 'day' => 'Saturday'],
    ['dow' => 7, 'day' => 'Sunday'],
];
```

I'm trying to loop through it in my blade template as follows:

```
 @foreach ($days as $day)
       <label>{{$day['day']}}</label>
       {!! Form::text('day_of_wk[$day['dow']].start_time', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
  @endforeach
```

But I get error: `syntax error, unexpected 'dow' (T_STRING)`

How can I add the `$day['dow']` value in my day_of_wk[] input array?

Comment: Take a look at the quotes around them. There is an syntax error. Remove the single Quotes or replace them by double quotes.

Comment: already tried that, it doesn't work. I think you can't add a variable in this manner when using laravel collective, unless someone can show me otherwise.

Comment: When I remove the single quotes I just get `$day[dow]` instead of the actual value

Comment: Managed to fix by doing the following `'day_of_wk['. $day['dow'] . '].start_time'`

Comment: You can embed variables in php strings only when using double quotes. With single quotes you need to concatenate it as you found above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  @foreach ($days as $day)
       <label>{{$day['day']}}</label>
       {!! Form::text('day_of_wk['.$day['dow'].'].start_time', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
  @endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach ($days as $day)
           <label>{{$day['day']}}</label>
           {!! Form::text("day_of_wk[{$day['dow']}].start_time", null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
      @endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

@foreach ($days as $day)
{{$day['day']}}
{!! Form::text("day_of_wk[{$day['dow']}].start_time", null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
@endforeach

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).